# sync to data occurrence in the same cycle

Tags: specman, e

I am using Sync in the following way:

```
sync true (ports.ocp_cmd$ == 3'b010);
```

I want the simulator to go to the next command the same cycle the data in `ocp_cmd is 010`. currently the simulator automatically jumps 1 cycle and only then goes to the next specman command.

How can I change my command line so that no delay is created (so that I will be able to raise the ack signal in the same cycle if desired)

Comment: You're going to have to clarify what you mean by "command".

Comment: by command I mean the next line in the e code:

Comment: sync true (ports.ocp_cmd$ == 3'b010);
          ports.ocp_read_accept$ = 1 ;

Comment: currently, the ocp_read_accept receives a value of 1 only 1 cycle after the occurrence of ocp_cmd == 010.  But I want the accept to rise in the same cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Since the sync true statement must reside in a time consuming method. Compare when the sampling event - for the time consuming method - occurs relative to the change in ocp_cmd becoming 3'b010.  It could be that you must modify your sampling event.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you mean that you sample `ocp_cmd` at the rising edge of the clock and this means you are raising `ocp_read` starting with that clock, which means the two signals will have a 1 cycle delay between each other.

If you know `ocp_cmd` doesn't glitch, you can change your sync to `sync true (ports.ocp_cmd$ == 3'b010) @sim`.

This isn't proper practice when working with synchronous signals. You'd be better of monitoring the cause of `ocp_cmd` going to `010` and relying on that.